# Spring 4 mvc RedirectView with BindingResult errors and RedirectAttributes and ModelAttribute

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have controller (POST|GET) and jsp view form (add person)

how can I make a redirect if I have a mistake - to see errors on the page in the fields INPUT ? bindingResult.hasErrors() == true ?

if ok i see **success** FlashAttribute

if i have error i see FlashAttribute **error** but i don't see mistake fields INPUT

```
   @RequestMapping(
            value = "/addUserProfile",
            method = RequestMethod.GET
            )
    public ModelAndView addUserProfile() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(VIEW_ADD_USER_PROFILE);
        return modelAndView;
    }

@ModelAttribute("userProfile")
UserProfile userProfile() {
    return new UserProfile();
}
```

and view addUserProfile.jsp

```
   <form:form id="data" action="/addUserProfile" method="POST" modelAttribute="userProfile" commandName="userProfile">
       <p><pre><code>${errorMessage}</code></pre></p>
       <p><pre><code>${id}</code></pre></p>
       <p><pre><code>${successMessage}</code></pre></p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="phone">phone</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="phone"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="phone" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="firstname">firstname</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="firstname"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="firstname" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <!--submit -->
            <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="submit"/></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
     </form:form>
```

Howto redirect to

```
 @RequestMapping(
            value = "/addUserProfile",
            method = RequestMethod.POST
    )
    public RedirectView addUserProfile(HttpServletRequest request,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("userProfile") UserProfile userProfile,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {

        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView(request.getRequestURI());

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage","error");
            redirectView.setContextRelative(true);
        } else {
             redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("successMessage","success");

            long id = userService.add(userProfile);
            redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("id",id);
        }



        return redirectView;
    }
```

Validate object form

```
public class UserProfile {
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 9, max = 20)
    private String phone;
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    private String firstname;
}
```

Comment: Howto see previously entered values if I have error bindingResult.hasErrors() == true ?

Comment: Put the userProfile ModelAttribute into Flash scope:  redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("userProfile",userProfile);